# Can't delete interesting tags in Mozilla (and other issues)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tag-watching

Some recent layout change seems to have caused brokenness in Mozilla (Debian Iceape 1.1.13). In order of decreasing seriousness:

- I can't delete interesting and ignored tags.
- I can't vote on comments.
- The "recent" letter icon in the header is not correctly positioned and becomes hard to click.

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you've cleared browser cache (aka take two asprins and call the doctor in the morning)
2. what the heck is "Iceape"?

We support the current and previous **official release*** versions of: Chrome, Safari, IE, Firefox, Opera.

Any open-source browsers based on the [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) (Chrome, Safari) or [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(layout_engine)) (Firefox) rendering engines should work fine as well.

edit: I downloaded [SeaMonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/) which is apparently the closest relative of IceApe (?) and I had no problems of any kind. I'm posting this from it in fact.. so as long as you've cleared cache I suspect some bugs in Debian's IceApe fork?

<sub>* betas at your own risk; we support *released* browsers only</sub>

Comment: Iceape is Debian's rebranded version of Mozilla. It is renamed to be free to make changes without approval of the Mozilla foundation, which controls the Mozilla trademark.

Comment: @starblue: They've changed the name *again*? Was “Iceweasel” too stable a name for them or something?

Comment: Iceweasel is Debian's Firefox, Iceape is Debian's Mozilla. BTW, this issue was the last straw for me to switch to Iceweasel. It still needs more work on userChrome.css to further reduce toolbar size and baroqueness.

Comment: @starblue. Do you mean Iceape is Debian's SeaMonkey?